# How can I use the mogrify command in Imagemagick to get color information of many images?

Tags: imagemagick, mogrify

I'm trying to get color information of many images and export this (preferably to a single txt file) using Imagemagick. I'm specifically looking for the number of pixels there are of each color. For a single image I use:

```
convert image.png -format %c histogram:info:result.txt
```

Which gives me what I need. A text file that contains:

```
 38775: (  0,255,  0) #00FF00 lime
   523: (255,  0,  0) #FF0000 red
 11756: (255,255,  0) #FFFF00 yellow
236946: (255,255,255) #FFFFFF white
```

I have been trying to do this for all the images using `mogrify` but without luck. As I mentioned I would ideally get all the information in a single file but separate files each containing the information would be great too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you are trying to do, or what would be the point, nor do I understand why you are so keen to use `mogrify` to achieve it... but I can create some images and tell you what's in them:

```
convert -size 10x10 xc:blue blue.png
convert -size 10x10 xc:red  red.png
convert -size 50x50 gradient:yellow-cyan -colors 8 mad.png
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

So, here we are:

```
convert red.png blue.png mad.png -depth 8 -format "%c" histogram:info:
       100: (255,  0,  0) #FF0000 red
       100: (  0,  0,255) #0000FF blue
       606: ( 33,255,222) #21FFDE srgb(33,255,222)
       613: ( 94,255,161) #5EFFA1 srgb(94,255,161)
         1: (128,255,128) #80FF80 srgb(128,255,128)
       641: (161,255, 94) #A1FF5E srgb(161,255,94)
       639: (224,255, 31) #E0FF1F srgb(224,255,31)
```

Or, with filenames too:

```
convert red.png blue.png mad.png -format "%f:%c" histogram:info:

red.png:       100: (255,  0,  0) #FF0000 red
blue.png:       100: (  0,  0,255) #0000FF blue
mad.png:       606: ( 8520,65535,57016) #2148FFFFDEB8 srgb(13%,100%,87%)
       613: (24248,65535,41287) #5EB8FFFFA147 srgb(37%,100%,63%)
         1: (32768,65535,32768) #8000FFFF8000 srgb(50%,100%,50%)
       641: (41287,65535,24248) #A147FFFF5EB8 srgb(63%,100%,37%)
       639: (57671,65535, 7864) #E147FFFF1EB8 srgb(88%,100%,12%)
```

Or with filenames at the start of each section:

```
convert red.png blue.png mad.png -format "%f\n%c" histogram:info:

red.png
         1: (255,  0,  0) #FF0000 red
blue.png
         1: (255,  0,  0) #FF0000 red
mad.png
       606: ( 8520,65535,57016) #2148FFFFDEB8 srgb(13%,100%,87%)
       613: (24248,65535,41287) #5EB8FFFFA147 srgb(37%,100%,63%)
         1: (32768,65535,32768) #8000FFFF8000 srgb(50%,100%,50%)
       641: (41287,65535,24248) #A147FFFF5EB8 srgb(63%,100%,37%)
       639: (57671,65535, 7864) #E147FFFF1EB8 srgb(88%,100%,12%)
```

Or maybe you mean this:

```
for f in *.png; do echo $f; convert "$f" -format %c histogram:info: ;done > result.txt
```

**result.txt**

```
blue.png
         1: (255,  0,  0) #FF0000 red
mad.png
       606: ( 8520,65535,57016) #2148FFFFDEB8 srgb(13%,100%,87%)
       613: (24248,65535,41287) #5EB8FFFFA147 srgb(37%,100%,63%)
         1: (32768,65535,32768) #8000FFFF8000 srgb(50%,100%,50%)
       641: (41287,65535,24248) #A147FFFF5EB8 srgb(63%,100%,37%)
       639: (57671,65535, 7864) #E147FFFF1EB8 srgb(88%,100%,12%)
red.png
         1: (255,  0,  0) #FF0000 red
```

What are you planning to do with the results - I suspect there is an easy way of achieving it...

Comment: `for f in *.png; do echo $f; convert "$f" -format %c histogram:info: ;done > result.txt` is actually what I meant.

I wanted to use `mogrify` because I could do it with `convert` and thought it would be the simplest way to do it for many images.

I'd like to use the results to analyse a number of maps I have scraped. On these maps, areas have a certain colour depending on their value. But I don't have the raw data to see how big the areas are (and the size changes continuously). I want to use these results to track how many pixels (and so how big of an area) there are of each colour.

Comment: Oh, cool project. You may want to think about choosing a palette of say 30 colours, and then remapping the colours to a common palette so all *"nearly pinks"* come out as a single standard pink and all *"nearly blues"* as a standard blue...

Comment: Thanks! Yeah that's exactly what I did. The original map is supposed to have just four colours but all the edges have shading and sometimes there were many 'mixed' pixels when areas with different colours shared a border. I managed to define all those and change them to the intended colour.